# XML data to list in c#

Tags: c#, .net

My xml data:

```
<products>
  <group groupcontractno="106" groupcontractversion="40">
      <product groupcontractno="106" groupcontractversion="40" cobno="1" productno="100" cobproductversion="4">
        <productname>Båtförsäkring</productname>
      </product>
      <product groupcontractno="106" groupcontractversion="40" cobno="1" productno="112" cobproductversion="1">
        <productname>Vattenskoterförsäkring</productname>
      </product>
  </group>
  <group>
   ...
  </grpup>
</products>
```

Model class:

```
public class GroupContract
{
    public string groupcontractno { get; set; }        
    public IList<Products> products { get; set; }

}

public class Products
{
    public string productname { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make list with `group` then in every `group` list has a `products` list.
And this is what I tried:

```
List<Products> productList = new List<Products>();
List<GroupContract> groupcontractList = groupedData.Descendants("group")
                                    .Select(d => new GroupContract
                                    {
                                        groupcontractname = d.Attribute("groupcontractno").Value,
                                        products = productList.Select(e => new Products
                                        {
                                            productname = d.Descendants("product").Descendants("productname").First().Value
                                        }).ToList()
                                    }).ToList();
```

It did create `group` lists but in `products` lists are empty, anyone can correct my code would be much appreciated!

Comment: at `products = productList.Select`, `productList` is empty, it has nothing to select.

Comment: How is this groupedData variable initialized?

Comment: @PankajKapare groupedData is the xml object

Comment: How about changing this line productname = d.Descendants("product").Descendants("productname").First().Value  to productname = d.Descendants("product").Descendants("productname").First().InnerText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query you're after:

```
List<GroupContract> groupcontractList = groupedData.Descendants("group")
                                .Select(d => new GroupContract
                                {
                                    groupcontractno = d.Attribute("groupcontractno").Value,
                                    products = d.Elements("product").Select(e => new Products
                                    {
                                        productname = d.Descendants("product").Descendants("productname").First().Value
                                    }).ToList()
                                }).ToList();
```

mainly, change:

```
products = productList.Select(...
```

to

```
products = d.Elements("product").Select(...
```

instead of `productList.Select`, use your group `d` and get all the `product` child elements into a list.  Then you can toss your `productList` variable.